# Difference between Super Mario 3D world versions differently rated

Tags: nintendo-switch, version-differences, super-mario-3d-world

I was searching for Super Mario 3D world for Switch and found 2 versions here on Amazon Spain: One is [7 years rated](https://www.amazon.es/-/pt/dp/B08HK3STN4/ref=sr_1_2?crid=G4D4VZ2CPR5W&keywords=super%2Bmario%2B3d&qid=1694419069&sprefix=super%2Bmario%2B3d%2Cspecialty-aps%2C110&sr=8-2&th=1) and the [other is free for all audiences](https://www.amazon.es/-/pt/dp/B08HJXRB1K/ref=sr_1_1?crid=G4D4VZ2CPR5W&keywords=super%20mario%203d&qid=1694419069&sprefix=super%20mario%203d%2Cspecialty-aps%2C110&sr=8-1).

Despite the minor cover, what are differences in these versions? By the logo used in rating system I assume 7 YO is Europe and free rating is USA version, but has the game some different content between them? Or maybe it's the same, but some aspects are quite enough to elevate the audience's age based in different guidelines from the regulators in one but not in another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at the two rating systems.

The [ESBR](https://www.esrb.org/ratings-guide/#rating_cat) goes straight from Everyone (everyone, all ages) to Everyone 10+

[image]
[image]

If we look to the back of the box it just mentions "mild carton violence", which isn't enough to give a clear cut answer.

[image]

Now let's look at [PEGI](https://pegi.info/)

[image]
[image]

Thanks to the content tagging system this time the box has more informations.

[image]

**It has the [Fear] tag!** And as you can see, the presence of "fear" element is the exact difference between the PEGI 3 and the PEGI 7 rating.

Basically it looks like that the rating boards identified the possibility that some of the elements in the game could scare little kids (Motley?). But the different ranges played a role: probably it was not enough to jump to a 10+ rating but enough to go to 7+....

Answer (score 2):

"E for everyone", despite the name, is [actually intended for audiences 6 and over](https://www.xbox.com/en-US/games/gameratings) - they're meant to be the same rating due to mild fantasy violence. The difference is whether they have a PEGI (Europe) rating or an ESRB (US) rating. The game is the same.